# "Поддомен" htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, поддомены, rewrite

Проблема с `.htaccess. и "симулятором поддомена", но`.htaccess` плохо разбираюсь.
Надо, чтобы путь http://site.ru/pages/ переименовывался на http://pages.site.ru/.

Пробовал так:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pages.site.ru$
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ pages/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Но не работало.

*P.S.* создать поддомен через ISP или другими способами - не вариант. Мне не надо поддомена, а просто чтобы в url была прикладка pages.site.ru .

Answer (score 1):

у меня так:

```
RewriteEngine on
#Склейка www.домен.ру с домен.ру
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
#редирект на поддомен
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru
RewriteRule my/(.*)$ http://my.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru/pages$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pages.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pages.site.ru$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages(?:/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L,QSA]
```